# promisify sails.js mongodb native()

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, native, bluebird

I'm using sails.js and bluebird promise with MongoDB as database, I need to use the Model.native() method for my Team model, the following code works:

```
Team.native(function (err, teamCollection) {
if (err) {
    return res.serverError(err);
}
teamCollection.update({_id: relatedTeamId}, {
    $set: {
        geoCoordinates: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [parseFloat(longitude), parseFloat(latitude)]
        },
        location: location
    }
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return res.serverError(err);
    }
    return res.send("OK");
});
```

});
However, I want to promisify this snippet of code, how may I do that?

```
Promise.promisify(Team.native)
```

doesn't seem to work..
The full code snippet of my attempt:

```
            ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
            relatedTeamId = new ObjectId(teamId);
            nativeModel = Promise.promisify(Team["native"]);
            return nativeModel().then(function (teamCollection) {
                var updater = Promise.promisify(teamCollection.update);
                return updater({_id: relatedTeamId}, {
                    $set: {
                        getCoordinates: {
                            type: "Point",
                            coordinates: [parseFloat(longitude, parseFloat(latitude))]
                        },
                        location: location
                    }
                }).then(function () {
                    return res.send('OK');
                })["catch"](function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return Promise.reject(err);
                });
            })["catch"](function (err) {
                return console.log('2');
            });
```

Yet the console gives me the following error message:

```
data:    app.js:3056 - [TypeError: Cannot read property 's' of undefined]
data:    app.js:3056 - 2
```

Comment: It should. But please show the complete code of your attempt.

Comment: Just did as per your request, please have a look, thanks

Comment: Ah, just what I had suspected. Btw, you might want to use `Promise.promisifyAll(Team)` instead, it simplifies a lot.

Comment: sorry? where is the spot you suspected and how to correct?

Comment: See the question I've closed this as a duplicate of… Both `nativeModel` and `updater` are called in no context.